# How to resolve "This expression is not callable" on union types?

Tags: typescript

Essentially, I have a class that extends some methods to a "proxy" of a row in a database table. The problem is, I can't get TypeScript to properly infer the set of keys (i.e. the columns on the relevant table) that can be passed based on the table.

Consider the following example:

```
type table1 = {id: number, col1: string, col2: string}
type table2 = {id: number, colA: number, colB: number}
type DBTable = table1 | table2
type DBColumnName<T extends DBTable> = keyof T
type DBColumnValue<T extends DBTable, C extends DBColumnName<T>> = T[C]

class ProxyDBRow<T extends DBTable> {
    data: T

    getColumn<C extends DBColumnName<T>>(name: C): DBColumnValue<T, C> {
            return this.data[name]
    }
}

// proxyComponent.svelte
export let proxy: ProxyDBRow<table1> | ProxyDBRow<table2>
export let attr: DBColumnName<table1> | DBColumnName<table2>

const gc = () => {
    proxy.getColumn(attr) // expression not callable error
}
```

In other words, I have a (svelte) component that I'm passing a proxy and the name of a column to, and I want to have type inference that the attribute being asked for is a valid column on that table.

I feel like unions are not really the proper solution here, but I don't know what is. I was looking into "conditional types" in the documentation but I can't really seem to get it to work. I need it to infer what the actual type of `attr` should be based on the type of the proxy, I just can't figure out how to write the expression properly.

Also I have tried annotating the type of proxy as `ProxyDBRow<table1 | table2>` but this doesn't work properly either: the union of the tables only allows for keys that all tables have in common, so for example, passing in a proxy of table1 would then raise an error if it detected something passing 'col1' into the getColumn method, since table2 doesn't have a key with that name.

Comment: I asked this question on the TS discord and was informed it may be related to a known issue called the "correspondence problem" https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55257

I'm still hopeful that someone can resolve this issue directly, but if it is true that a work-around is necessary for the current version of TypeScript, you can see [this Reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/15r139a/how_to_resolve_the_expression_not_callable_on/jw6be1y/) for more implementation specific details including links to the actual repo I'm working on.

Comment: You'll need some sort of guarantee that `proxy` and `attr` have a relationship with each other stronger than union membership.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgKX4w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The issue is that `proxy` could be either type and `attr` could be the *keys* of either type but there's nothing at the type-level in your code that prevents a mismatch of the keys of one type with the value of the other. You need to narrow the types or make gc generic.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, thanks! I'd love to see your write up, but I think I can already see how I want to implement that approach as a solution. Thanks for the timely response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with

```
let proxy: ProxyDBRow<Table1> | ProxyDBRow<Table2>
let attr: DBColumnName<Table1> | DBColumnName<Table2>
```

is that each variable is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) but they are independent of each other.  So `proxy` could be, say, a `ProxyDBRow<Table2>`, while `attr` is `DBColumnName<Table1>`; for example:

```
let proxy = new ProxyDBRow<Table1>();
let attr = "colB";
```

You wouldn't want the compiler to allow `proxy.getColumn(attr)` in such a case, so there's a good reason for the error.

---

You would like to represent `proxy` and `attr` as some sort of *correlated* unions.  But TypeScript doesn't really have direct support for correlated unions.  You could actually express this relationship:

```
declare let [proxy, attr]:
    [ProxyDBRow<Table1>, DBColumnName<Table1>] |
    [ProxyDBRow<Table2>, DBColumnName<Table2>]
```

But you'd have the same problem:

```
proxy.getColumn(attr); // still error
```

The lack of direct support for correlated union types is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

The recommended approach to dealing with these is to switch away from unions toward [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  Depending on the use case you might have to go for a fairly major refactoring as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

But in this case we don't have to change much. I'd just give `proxy` and `attr` types that depend on a generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `DBTable`:

```
function gcFor<T extends DBTable>(proxy: ProxyDBRow<T>, attr: DBColumnName<T>) {
    return () => {
        proxy.getColumn(attr); // okay
    }
}
```

That works because no matter what `T` is, `proxy` is known to have a `getColumn()` method which accepts an argument of type `DBColumnName<T>`, which `attr` matches.

And callers of `gcFor()` will see some protection against mismatches:

```
const gc1 = gcFor(new ProxyDBRow<Table1>(), "col2"); // okay
const gc2 = gcFor(new ProxyDBRow<Table2>(), "colB"); // okay
const gcOops = gcFor(new ProxyDBRow<Table1>(), "colB"); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&filetype=ts#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQIxQLxQN5QJYAmAXFAHYCuAtghAE4A0UAxgPZKokDOwtepA5o1ZIATFx59+UAL4BYAFChIsRChGYc+YmSo0GzNgEESFanSFsAQid10ZCpdAAil+MmhY3KdAB8V7kQdwZ0sAYTYqUgA5OEoIAB4YKAgAD2AIUgJOKBcvCAA+DQBrCBAWADNYIOUXcKRIgDU4eoSk1PTM7NzVCEZQ5LSMrJywiMpo2Nb8ws8AbVCAXQUFJiQ4TmyABVoWFJAXACUWAHdEgY7h7vdC7AUoe6gCOGA4EiSsCiQkAEJl+QeoPwIMA6pF4v12kMuqN6uMYnFEtMABSkSYkUIAShItTGpCaLUSfRudwBD1owPItFIUGAAAs8JwAHRPF6zVFxJb-B5yeQ8hTlcikJjAPAsan8JgAMRYtDOkM6Izy+SRYB2exI212+0sR1OMHyjGePGxMMi8KmGJwJPu5OAlOpSMtGGJXNJUFVWsZQJBuKRRtoGIA3Nb7Ly-qxSNxAUx0FgJdLaCiIMcoJq9ocTokeqhlRjGAAiYQifNBqAAejLUBYRTgIBWYqjEvUcalMqTKbT2t1WYCuYLwksJcD5cr1dr9cjwGjAHkWGBsi2E+3U2qu5m8jnHf2rEOR8laDtaH92RBOGA4ExoDB6ZwnCxT1EWMAAOoyopW12PCCrODkqAoKdZg9PZDWAHgFiIEMAVmTsMz1bMDRGUE4UmHtvHyBYoB8KCHhg1c4LQiAREQnFYQmBE8mIzkQ2AkAvWBZDSD9MCA2HCsoG4PAvn3Q8-mkIA)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but I think I overlooked a reason why I can't actually implement this in my (Svelte) application: 'attr' needs to be a prop that can be passed to the component. Even if I strongly associate the types within the wrapper function, I'm just passing the problem to a different variable. It seems like there just isn't a way to do what I want to do without having a way to explicitly tell TypeScript the type of 'attr' depends on what 'proxy' is: https://tsplay.dev/N5Ve2m

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about this followup question, now that I've answered the question after first checking with you that it met your needs.  If it doesn't actually meet your needs, what can I do?  You can tell the compiler that `attr` and `proxy` are related by using generics.  Your playground link has something like `ProxyDBRow<DBTable>` which is a different thing and would require you redefine `DBColumnName` to match, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDAkzm), but who knows if that's what you want?  I think if you have further problems you might want to create a new post for it.